# OAuth-AS3 library "Access of undefined property oauth."

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, twitter-oauth

I'm having a problem using Action Script 3.0 OAuth to integrate it with Twitter.

For those who develops in Flash/ActionScript may know these two libraries:

[High level AS3/Flex library for OAuth](http://soenkerohde.com/2009/07/high-level-as3flex-library-for-oauth-with-twitter-from-air/)

[oauth-as3](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-as3/)

I'm having problem when ever I test the flash, here are the errors I'm getting:

```
/Users/Testing.as, Line 20  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method OAUth.
/Users/Testing.as, Line 20  1188: Illegal assignment to class IOAuth.
/Users/Testing.as, Line 22  1120: Access of undefined property oauth.
/Users/Testing.as, Line 34  1180: Call to a possibly undefined method OAUth.
```

I just copied the code from the first link page and past. Everything seems fine but I don't know what's the issue. Still a beginner here.  I've imported all the libraries correctly too.

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import org.flaircode.oauth.*;
import org.iotashan.oauth.*;


public class Testing extends MovieClip {

    private var consumerKey:String = "KEYKEYHERE"; // hidden for privacy purposes
    private var consumerSecret:String = "KYEKEYKEYHERE"; // hidden for privacy purposes

    public function Testing() {
        // constructor code
        ini();
    }

    public function ini():void{
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, whenClicked);
    }


    function whenClicked():void{
        // create OAuth
        oauth:IOAuth = new OAUth(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        // get request token
        var loader:URLLoader = oauth.getRequestToken("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, requestTokenHandler);

    }

    function requestTokenHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        requestToken = OAuthUtil.getTokenFromResponse(e.currentTarget.data as String);
        var request:URLRequest = oauth.getAuthorizeRequest("http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize", requestToken.key);
        // opens website where user has to login on Twitter and gets 6 digit pin code
        navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
    }

    function getAccessToken(pin:int):void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = oauth.getAccessToken("http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", requestToken, {oauth_verifier:pin});
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, accessTokenHandler);
    }

    function accessTokenHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        accessToken = OAuthUtil.getTokenFromResponse(e.currentTarget.data as String);
        // TODO store accessToken.key and accessToken.secret in EncryptedLocalStorage for all further requests
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line:

```
oauth:IOAuth = new OAUth(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
```

to:

```
var oauth:OAuth = new OAUth(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
```

I see the same problems with the vars: 'requestToken' and 'accessToken'.  You need to declare them as variables by putting a 'var' in front of them; ie, "var myVar:VarType". Also, if you declare these vars inside the functions in which they're created, then they'll only be visible inside these functions.  If you want them to be visible to the entire class, declare them as class variables, just as you've done with the keys: ie, "private var requestToken:String;"

Comment: I will try that tomorrow. Sorry for my delay.